# Redux-way in the real life

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to ask the community about an ideological problem.
Lets imagine todo-list on react/redux, you have single state where todoItems array is served. But now lets imagine I want to have few components on the page that are render todoItems with different UI. And I need to update each these components on CRUD of todoItems. What is your architectural approach of this issue? Don't forget we have a large database and we can get todoItems with pagination only.

**Update:**

Lets make it clear. When we implement redux life cycle with this UI we have 2 options:

1) Serve one array of todoItems into singleton redux state object.
Advantages: all our components will updates by object changing.
Problems: we can't get ALL data from our database, but have to show different paginated/filtered data, so we can't implement pagination/filtering on frontend-side. We have a few different components and the have to render different objects collection. So it doesn't fit.

2) We can use different keys into our global redux state. 
Advantages: we can independently get data for each component
Problems: other components will not feel when object changing in one of them. In this case we have to write custom code.

I just want to know maybe I'm missing something and we have other option or maybe someone have good architectural approach to this problem.

Comment: What is the problem you see here in redux way? You still have single state tree,which can be updated as you wish, so you can organize caching of things, etc, so if data is large or paginated,it won't be problem at all.

Comment: I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet your complications come from the point of view which unfortunately quite common among `redux` community: trying to keep `redux` shape as close to UI shape as possible.

Try no to think about `redux` state as a substitute for the `Component` states. What `redux` should know about is actual todos only (id, title, date of creation, etc.). Let `Component`-specific data like pagination stuff live in `Components` state. When user goes to next page in one of the `Components` what should be updated is this `Component` state (`pageNumber`, `from`, `to`, `amount`, etc.). `redux` should be updated only in case necessary todos are missing.

The useful analogy is to thinking about your `redux` as good old SQL-database: `redux` store state is data itself, `selectors` and `actions` are queries and stored procedures, `React Components` are views with selected data.

**Update:** Ok, seems like what you are looking for is *state normalization*. Separate `todos` details from the lists of `ids`. This way updates of `todo` fields will be sensed by all the `Components`. On the other hand you'll be able to keep separate collections of `todos` in different `Components`. Namely make state look like this:

```
{
   funnyTodos: [ 'id1', 'id2' ],
   boringTodos: [ 'id3', 'id4' ],
   recentlyDoneTodos: [ 'id1' ],
   todos: {
     id1: { name: .... },
     id2: { name: .... },
     id3: { name: .... },
     id4: { name: .... },
   }
}
```

Implementing pagination in this case is just a matter of getting list of `todos` `ids` for the next page from back-end and then loading missing `todos` for given `ids`.